# MS SQL connection error

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, ado.net, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a C# application with a MSSQL 2008R2 Database.
Database is in single user state.
I used ADO.NET to connecting to the database. 
So I create a SqlConnection and execute my command using it in C#.

Like this :

```
using (var con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString.ToString()))
{
    using (var cmd = con.CreateCommand())
    {
        con.Open();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandTimeout = CommandTimeoutSeconds;
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = sqlSelect;
        try
        {
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                columns.Add(reader[0].ToString());
            }
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            logger.Error("Во время отработки запроса произошла ошибка. \nТекст ошибки: {0}.\nStackTrace: {1}.}",
                ex.Message, ex.StackTrace);
            throw ex;
        }
    }
}
```

But it got exception : 
"Can not open database "db_name", requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user "sa"`.

Why this happened‌ ?
How to handle it ?

Is not connection string error, i'm check this at every step.

only one connection string use for this application and connection in other places of code is correct. 
app inserting data from file in 20 tables and give me error message on 15th table, after another start of app error are genereted on 10th table or 17th and etc. sometime app worked without error.

Comment: What does this mean in English: `"Не удается открыть базу данных "db_name", запрашиваемую именем входа. Не удалось выполнить вход. Ошибка входа пользователя "sa".`, please edit your question.

Comment: "Can not open database "db_name", requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user "sa"."

Comment: password to login for 'sa' is wrong in connection string.

Comment: or user "sa" does not exist

Comment: Please post your connection string.

Comment: connection string is not wrong. I use it more than once in this project. this error are generated in the different places of application.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is, that *login failed*. Check your database credentials in your connection string or make sure Windows Authentication is enabled on the database if that's what you are using.

Comment: connection string is not wrong. I use it more than once in this project. this error are generated in the different places of application.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're trying to connecting to the database using an unvalid  Database-Login.
You used **SA** Login in the connection string, are you sure that you set Mix-Mode (Password of the System Administrator/SA) while installing MSSQL‌ Server2008 ?

Any way I offer to cerate a new Database-Login.
If you don't know how, follow this link :
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337562.aspx

Comment: no, only one connection string use for this application, and connection in other places of code is correct. app inserting data from file in  20 tables and give me error message on 15th tables, after another start of app error are genereted on 10th tables or 17th and etc. sometime app working without error.

Comment: So your unpredictable error! may be related to the Command.TimeOut
What's the max count of records that you've have in your tables ?

Comment: 3.000.000 records. I'm change connection timeout and comand timeout, set this equal 60 seconds.

Comment: It seems every thing is alright! 
I offer to trace your application and see what is exactly happening when it throw exception to find out what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to create a connection string is as follows

Step1: Create a text file (Mycon.txt), then rename the extension to (Mycon.udl).

Step2: Now double click the Universal Data link file(Mycon.udl).

Step3: Provider Tab: Select the Microsoft OLEDB Provider for SQL Server,
        Connection Tab: enter server,username & Password and test connection.

Step4: If the Test connection is success. click ok and close it.

Step5: Open the Mycon.udl file with Notepad. And copy the connection string.